# Reply with a 500 response?

Tags: nock

If I do

```
nock('http://example.com').put('/foo', {foo: 'bar'}).reply(500)
```

Then I don't get a `500` response. Instead, I get an error: `"RequestError: Nock: No match for request..."`. How do I return an actual 500 response in this case?

Comment: See https://github.com/nock/nock/issues/1515